# App launches manually OK, but when launched from Installer it fails (error:an .OCX as Unregistered) Why?

Tags: vb6, ocx

Our installer (old version of the WISE installer) uses the ShellExecute to launch a program (MyApp.exe) it has installed. But when we do that Windows 7 balks and says that Richtx32.ocx is not registered or is missing a component.

-If I manually launch MyApp.exe from Explorer, it runs just fine.
-If I run a .Bat file that launches MyApp.exe, it runs just fine.
-If I move my installer to the same directory that MyApp.exe is in an run it from there I get the same error.

- Windows 7, 32 bit.
- An older RichTx32.ocx is installed in the \Windows\System directory.
- In testing on VMware (Windows 7, 32 bit, without RichTxt32.ocx installed) this problem does NOT happen.
- The RichTx32.ocx I install happens to have the o capitalized (.Ocx) and then the system reports the error it refers to  *my* OCX (RichTx32.Ocx) or one of it's components being unregistered.

One thought I just had is that the installer may be running as the Admin user and maybe when it launches another app that app doesn't run as the same user, but if you launch from a .bat file it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That apper be an about access control and administrative privileges

Try changed

ShellExecute(NULL, "open", szGadgetSource, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

for

ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, szGadgetSource, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

or

turned out to access control

Comment: I can't change the ShellExecute paramaters used by the installer. However, if I were to include a Manifest that forced MyApp.exe to launch as ADMININSTRATOR, would that avoid the problem?

Comment: I tested both ShellExecute methods from VB6 and both fail. However, disabling Access Control fixes the problem.

Comment: This question needs to be edited to make it simpler. I'll do that unless you prefer that I do not.

Answer (score 0):

try compile it as an installer, not just and exe.., then install it in your system.., an installer package, not just an compiled exe file. some active controls/dll/active x will not be copied if you just save it as an exe file

Comment: Good thinking. But... I tried that (actually *installing* the VB .exe rather than just copying it.) Same problem.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the RICHTX32.OCX into system directory.

1) try to run this code in the RUN regsvr32.exe c:\windows\system32\RICHTX32.OCX or drag the file to REGSVR32.EXE.

2) right click your EXE application, goto properties, compatibility, then check Run this program .... in the compatibility mode and privileged level.

hope that helps..,